# How to get max value of one field from index with condition on another part

Tags: lua, tarantool

Let's suppose that i have space with tree indexes on field 1, 2 and {1,2} with following tuples:

- [1, 1]
- [2, 1]
- [3, 1]
- [4, 2]
- [5, 2]
- [6, 2]
- [7, 3]
- [8, 3]
- [9, 3]

what is the fastest way to retrieve tuple with max value of field 1 and where field 2 is equal 2, AFAIK pairs doesn't support partial keys, so there is any way without iterating through partial select results?

Answer (score 1):

Composite index should have order {2, 1} then tuple with max value of 1st field and specific value of 2nd field can be selected by:

```
index:select({2}, {iterator='REQ',limit=1})[1]
```